# Is there a "standard" approach for handling HttpConnection errors in Android (e.g. no Internet)

Tags: android, http

I have a method which calls an endpoint via `GET` request. I was sure, checking for internet before the operation would be the best approach, BUT:

**1)** What if the internet connection is lost during the operation?
**2)** Pinging Google DNS to check for a connection, what if the internet provider blocks pings to it?

Is it better to connect to the endpoint, get the data from there and if it fails (No internet - `UnknownHostException`) handle it on demand or not?

Comment: it's possible that, between the time you check if a user has internet access and the call going through, the user loses internet connectivity. so your requests should handle timeouts and error responses, instead of checking for internet the entire time, that's my opinion :D

Comment: So, regarding making connections using HttpUrlConnection, when there is no internet, will it trigger UnknownHostException or a timeout :)?

Comment: you should be handling both, as there could potentially be internet, but your api you're using just doesn't respond

Comment: posted an answer now, just to be complete :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, connectivity is never a certain fact and the possibility of losing connection OR your request failing for any number of reasons is always there. To properly handle service calls (in my opinion at least) always consider the possibility of either your user losing internet or your service call not returning at all, as well as any other error responses which you could receive from the actual request. Handle the response per call and consider the possibility of your request entirely failing or timing out as well.

For `HttpURLConnection`, you'd use `getErrorStream` as one of the methods to determine any errors.

[image]

Comment: would it be possible to add an example of getErrorStream? I am confused, when I use it do I still have to check for Exceptions?

Comment: getErrorStream will potentially tell you what the error was when something has failed, it's all in the documentation : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream() . I personally dont use HttpURLConnection so can't give you any examples

Comment: Ps. Do I even need the getErrorStream, If I don't care If a 404 is thrown...? I just want to fetch a json, if it fails okay retry...